# get data from model in view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have two tables
  Category and book
My Category table with the book table has one-to- many links,that's mean  one category can have several books
Now I want to display 6 books from each category on my homepage
How should I get the information?

Comment: Please consider including the program code you have tried, it further helps whoever wants to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

May I sugguest **select_related** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/

> Returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships, selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query. This is a performance booster which results in a single more complex query but means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require database queries.

Assuming your **Category** model has a column with **id** name.

```
book_category_with_id_1 = Book.objects.select_related('Category')
.filter(colInBookModelThatisForeignKeytoCategoryModel__id=1)
```

To limit to 6:

```
book_category_with_id_1 = Book.objects.select_related('Category')
.fitler(colInBookModelThatisForeignKeytoCategoryModel__id=1).order_by('id')[:6]
```

One way to get that for every **Category** you'd have to query **Category** table first, loop through those ids and carry out the above query with each id.

Comment: My problem is writing this last  loop

Comment: Sharing part of the code in your question helps us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Views.py

```
def Categories (request):
 all_categories = Category.objects.all()
 return render(request, 'your_template.html, {'all_categories' : all_categories})
```

Your_template.html

```
{% for category in all_categories %}
{% for book in category.children|slice:":6" %}
Bookt title : {{ book.name  }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```